# log file not created instead written to console

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I am using the new log file for each run as mentioned here:
http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/

Below is what i have in my `log4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="toFile" class="com.ram.util.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="./logs/log.txt" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %30.30C [%t] %30.30M %L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="toFile" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

When i run my code this is what i see:

`log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [ALL].
log4j: root level set to ALL
log4j: Class name: [com.ram.util.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [./logs/log.txt].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %30.30C [%t] %30.30M %L - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: .\logs\log-1411675515571.txt, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [toFile] to category [root].
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Documents and Settings\ram0001\Local Settings\Temp\testng-eclipse-1777833329\testng-customsuite.xml`

and then everything is written to the console..what wrong i am doing here?

Any help??

Comment: Do you see this "log-1411675515571.txt" file created in the logs folder?

Comment: No, the log file is not created

Comment: Check if you have any other similar log4j.xml file anywhere else in your classpath? Also How does the code look ?